# Can I remove the default Apache2 sites?

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost

I'm setting up my first Apache2 server and having a bit of an issue. I want to have several VirtualHosts that are pointed to by separate domains, which I have working correctly. However, when you simply type in the server IP address, it displays the first declared virtualhost (it used to display the default apache2 page, but I ran:

```
$ a2dissite default
```

Now the ip address displays the first declared virtualhost. Is it possible to force the ip address to display nothing, while the domains display their respective folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got the desired result by reenabling default with:

```
$ a2ensite default
```

and the disabling directory indexing by changing "Indexes" to "-Indexes" in the default file under sites-available. It now throws a 403 Forbidden error.